# Using process substitution with HereDocument that is stored in a variable

Tags: bash, heredoc

I know I can use bash's process substitution feature to specify a file parameter via process substitution and then use a here document to specify the data, like so:

```
foo --config <(cat <<EOF
# contents of config file
...
EOF
)
```

When I need the same here document at two different locations in the same script, then it would be more useful to store the here document in a variable.

How can I do something like this:

```
read -r -d '' MY_CONFIG <<EOF
# contents of config file
...
EOF
```

Then how can I call `foo` to pass the contents of `$MY_CONFIG` to the `--config` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution occurred to my while writing this question. Rather then using `<(cat ...)`, we can use `<(echo ...)` to write something from the process substitution. So we can simply use:

```
foo --config <(echo "$MY_CONFIG")
```

A simple example to test this would be this:

```
MY_CONFIG="hello world"
less -f <(echo "$MY_CONFIG")
```

This should open less and show `hello world` in the buffer.

Comment: `less` may give a false positive: `less -f <<<"$MY_CONFIG"` produces the same result as your example, but does so using stdin not a file. To better approximate your desired usage, consider `md5sum <( echo "$MY_CONFIG" )` vs. `md5sum <<< "$MY_CONFIG"`.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can use a `herestring` inside of process substitution:

```
MY_CONFIG="hello world"
md5sum <( <<< "$MY_CONFIG" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider the solution you found yourself simpler, but for sake of completeness, here is how you could do it with here-docs.

To store a here-doc in a variable, you can use (`>` is the secondary prompt string):

```
$ var=$(cat <<EOF
> line1
> line2
> EOF
> )
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="line1
line2"
```

Then, to use a here-doc with the contents of that variable:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> $var
> EOF
line1
line2
```

I.e., for your case, something like this:

```
$ foo --config <(cat <<EOF
> $var
> EOF
> )
```

As I said, it's clearly simpler to just use `<(echo "$var")` or `<(printf '%s\n' "$var")` instead.